# Lookup table from .mat file running batch (RSIM)

Tags: matlab, batch-file, code-generation, lookup-tables, matlab-coder

At the moment I have a lookup table in a Simulink model which is reading the first and second columns from the workspace; in other words, I put the names of my vector variables in these fields. Then, I generated the code using rsim.tlc, run the batch and got the expected results. Nevertheless, when I try to run the batch again changing the vectors (they have different length in comparison with the ones I used when compiled the executable), I always get a message which says that the checksum number mismatches. I already verified if the rtP structure correctly reads the new values I´m using in my lookup table, thus I have no idea how to solve this.

Could someone help me?

As additional information, my target is to output the number if a second column of the lookuptable based on a clock number which is seek in the first column of the table. I would not mind using a .mat in the table, but I don´t have any idea how to do so.

I would appreacite any hint to solve this.

Don´t hesitate to ask me for more info! thanks in advance

Comment: Can you put the full error and your code?

Comment: Sure. It says: Error reading parameter data from mat-file: model checksum mismatch - incorrect parameter data specified. What I am doing is changing the values of the matrices in the workspace, loading the rtp structure with the new values (according to workspace), save the new structure in a different mat-file and running the script with that new structure.